# c# string array reference

Tags: c#, listviewitem

I'm new to c# but struggling with some fairly basic assignments.

This works:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" });
```

This Does not:

```
string[] rrr = new string[4]{ "1", "2", "3", "4" };
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] rrr);
```

My Final goal is:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    rrr[i] = "SomeText";
}
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] rrr);
```

Apologies for the basic question, I've not been able to find the right keywords to get a solution. I'm more used to VBA which allows me to get away with anything.....

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `new[] rrr` to do? I suspect you just want `new ListViewItem(rrr)`

Comment: VBA allows you to write and run anything. It does not stop the code from not working.

Comment: try this `new ListViewItem(rrr);`

Comment: I actually suspect he wants `new ListViewItem(Enumerable.Range(1, i).ToArray())` or `new ListViewItem(Enumerable.Repeat("SomeText", i).ToArray())`

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. You could have mentioned that this doesn't compile and which line which does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do only this

```
string[] rrr = new string[4]{ "1", "2", "3", "4" };
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(rrr);
```

so:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    rrr[i] = "SomeText";
}
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(rrr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and again, sorry for the basic question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] rrr);` use `ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(rrr);`